# How do I send a new position to my 5 dof robot arm?

Tags: ros2, control, position

I am a newbie with ros2 control.  I am using ros2 iron on Ubunto 22.04 (Linux Mint).  I made a copy of the ros2_control demo example #7.

This is the one that is launched with the command `ros2 launch ros2_control_demo_example_7  r6bot_controller.launch.py`, I changed the name as well as urdf file.  I also interfaced it with my Arduino robot arm based on positions.  My arm has 5 instead of 6 joints and only uses positions.  There are no encoders on my arm.  All the velocity commands and states related to velocity were taken out of example 7.  In my hardware interface (copy), I have code that when a position is changed, the code should send off a state change to an Arduino robot arm...

When I run  `ros2 control list_controllers`, I see

```
jem_5dof_robot_arm_controller[jem_robot_arm/RobotController] active    
joint_state_broadcaster[joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster] active
```

When I run `ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces`, I see

```
command interfaces
    Joint1/position [available] [claimed]
    Joint2/position [available] [claimed]
    Joint3/position [available] [claimed]
    Joint4/position [available] [claimed]
    Joint5/position [available] [claimed]
state interfaces
    Joint1/position
    Joint2/position
    Joint3/position
    Joint4/position
    Joint5/position
```

I also see am image of my robot arm in rviz... I would say "things look like they are working"

My question is this...........

How do I send a new position to my robot arm from the command line or a GUI.  Either send one new position for a Joint or send the set of positions for all 5 joints.  All I want to happen is, quickly send something and interact with the Arduino hardware.  I believe the code I implemented in the hardware interface to my Arduino based arm will work, the question is how to I force something to call my hardware interface with an update (so as to test).  I'd like to set a few different positions and see if the hardware is working ok.  Ideally, it would be nice to make changes in rviz and send those changes to my arm/Arduino.  I suspect that rviz is only a one way visualization of the arm and has no way to move something.  I suspect that once a new position is sent to my robot arm's controller [jem_5dof_robot_arm_controller], rviz will update accordingly.

What are is a simple way to send off a few new positions from the command line to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question: do you really need a custom controller, or might work a [position_controller](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/position_controllers/doc/userdoc.html) (simple interface, topic with one position-vector per received topic) or the [joint trajectory controller](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/doc/userdoc.html) (has also a topic interface, but additionally an action server; and it interpolates optionally from a full trajectory, not only from a single point).

Have a look at the [other examples](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_1/doc/userdoc.html) from the demos on how to use them.

Comment: I should have spent more time choosing an example/start with the basics.  Example 1 looks like a good way to go.  One of the major pulls for my starting with Example 7 was that it was described as "A full tutorial for a 6 DOF robot."  Example 6 also included a displayable arm in RVIZ.  I also made a new cad model.  My arm displayes correctly.  I am  trying to use .... ros2 topic pub /jem_5dof_robot_arm_controller/joint_trajectory trajectory_msgs/msg/JointTrajectory {  joint_names: [ "Joint1", "Joint2"], "points": [ {"positions": [ 1 2 3 ] }, { "positions": [ 2 1 0 ]  ] } to affect the arm.

Comment: I reimplemented my project as Example 1 in the demo and can move forward..

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as solving the question (there should be a green tick mark next to it).